# Set up directory traversal barrier

Tags: php, apache2

I'm trying to make my web server more secure, right now i'm attempting to put up a sort of "barrier" against directory traversal so a malicious user could not pass this if they found a way to perform such an attack.

The way I'm trying to do this is by having a folder layout as such:
( www being the furthest apache is allowed to go.)

```
/www/public_html/ #public contents
    / #private contents
```

I've found a way to deny all access after the web root, but i need things like PHP to be able to access private files like this

`include '../private_file.php';`

This is what i have so far in apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /www/public_html>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Directory>` restrictions only control access over HTTP, not access by scripts running in the web server. They're not what you want here.

What you're looking for is the PHP [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) configuration option.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me from going insane after Googling it for 3 hours